# Importing txt file into python as an array splits double digits as separate values

Tags: python, arrays, save, load

When I import a file and turn all the information into an array, for some reason it reads double digit number as separate digits and splits them like so:

```
'add' [2, 0]
```

The code I use is the following:

```
if oper == "or":
    direction = open("directions.txt", "r")
    direct = direction.readlines(1)
    direct = direct[0].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    direction.close()
    Or = open(direct+".txt", "r")
    content2 = Or.readlines(1) #Reads the first line in file
    content2 = content2[0].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    numbers2 = content2.split(", ")
    numbersAdd = list(map(int, numbers2[1]))
    numbersSub = list(map(int, numbers2[3]))
    numbersDiv = list(map(int, numbers2[5]))
    numbersMult = list(map(int, numbers2[7]))
    print("These are the answers: \noutput/:")
    print(numbers2[0],numbersAdd)
    print(numbers2[2],numbersSub)
    print(numbers2[4],numbersDiv)
    print(numbers2[6],numbersMult)
    print("")
```

Information stored on the file is the following:

```
[['add', 20], ['sub', 0], ['div', 0], ['mult', 0]]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval()` to read the whole line from your file as a list of lists.

Comment: So where would I place this in here?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(content2)`

Comment: Could you make this an answer?

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval(content2[0])` to read the whole line from your file as a list of lists.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(content2)
    NameError: name 'ast' is not defined`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stefan\Videos\School work\save.py", line 407, in <module>
    ast.literal_eval(content2)
  File "C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ast.py", line 85, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ast.py", line 84, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: ["[['add', 0], ['sub', 0], ['div', 0], ['mult', 0]]"]`

Comment: I made a change to my answer.